# React page, adding a button which uses innerHtml but cant call a react action

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, innerhtml

Learning react so please bear with....
Using a button click the user can add a new room

```
   @action
      newRoomClicked = async (event, meta) => {
    //do something
    
    //in here I have also added a remove btn beside the new room, allowing the user to remove the room
    
    var removeRoomBtn = document.createElement('button');
        removeRoomBtn.type = 'button';
        removeRoomBtn.textContent = 'Remove';
    removeRoomBtn .setAttribute('onClick','document.getElementById("' + newDivRoomId + '").remove();document.getElementById("btnUpdateRoomRemoval").click();');

 Div.appendChild( removeRoomBtn );
    }
```

which calls:

```
   <button style={{ display: "none" }} type="button" id="btnUpdateRoomRemoval" onClick={this.removeRoomUpdateRunningFee}/>
```

which on click calls

```
 @action
   removeRoomUpdateRunningFee  = event => {
      this.numberOfNewRooms = parseInt(this.numberOfNewRooms)-1;
      this.handleRunningFeeChangeRoom();
  }
```

This works, but as you can see its messy. I want to tidy it up.
I want to replace the `removeRoomBtn.setAttribute('onClick','document.getElementById("' + newDivRoomId + '").remove();document.getElementById("btnUpdateRoomRemoval").click();');`

with code that calls the action

```
@action
   removeRoomUpdateRunningFee  = event => {
      this.numberOfNewRooms = parseInt(this.numberOfNewRooms)-1;
      this.handleRunningFeeChangeRoom();
  }
```

directly and passes in the newDivRoomId as a param, in the event (so I can remove the btn and call handleRunningFeeChangeRoom()):
Have been trying a few ways etc:

```
   removeRoomBtn.setAttribute('onClick','this.removeUpdateRunningFee');
    //removeRoomBtn.setAttribute('onClick','this.removeRoomUpdateRunningFee()');
 //removeRoomBtn.setAttribute('onClick','this.removeRoomUpdateRunningFee(newDivRoomId )');
```

Just cant seem to get it.

Any help please?

Comment: Very little of this looks like how React works. Where are you learning all this from?

Comment: Yes I agree... its a make shift hack at the minute which I intend to resolve but just want to tidy it for now